# best options for maps when programming for blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-maps

I see there are java sdk and webworks sdk for blackberry, with bb 5, 6, and now 7 os systems in existance... play adobe air and webworks for the playbook.  I'm looking to port an android app over to BB.  I need to have the maps part of the app be responsive, with the pinch zoom pan, etc fast and looking as good as on Android or iOS with their built in maps.  Without buying a third-party license, which sdk for BB would be best, and do they have in the API what I need?

Answer (score 1):

For a hobby project I've used Google maps in 3 different ways: first as static image, as Javascript and finally as flash/flex component.

(1) Static image is the easiest one to use.

(2) Javascript are the most lightweight and quick to load at a web page.

(3) [Flash/flex](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http://flex.org/tour/&ei=z6HOTa_5GMKk-gb8_oCjDA&usg=AFQjCNGngtceHmSsgeWcATW_eHrU1G80zw&sig2=9nsz238IDj0AiOW29dxKQw) is the most advanced and responsive.

But: (3) won't work with BB 5, 6, 7. It will work only with Playbook. (2) will work with BB 6, 7 but not very comfortable...

Also you could use Blackberry [Mapfield](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Map_field_1299236_11.jsp), which won't however work with Playbook - until BB Java SDK has been released for it.

And you could wait for Android Java SDK for Playbook too, but it won't work for BB 5, 6 , 7.

Just FYI, not trying to give a complete answer.

Comment: I ended with static image for 5.0 and JavaScript map for 6.0, shown by detecting OS version..

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the same code base to work on BB OS 6 and 7 (OS 5 is now supported a lot less) as well as the PlayBook is to use the WebWorks SDK. Since WebWorks is based on HTML and JavaScript, you have lots of options for maps:

- Google Maps API (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/)
- Yahoo! Maps API (http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/)
- Bing Maps API (http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx)
- MapQuest SDK (http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/javascript)
- MapQuest Open Source SDK (http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/sdk)

Hope that these resources can get you started!